# How do I minimize decimal place to 0?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, decimal

Currently, I'm retrieving data from a SharePoint Site, and I'm able to do so, however, I want limit the decimal place to 0.

```
if (item["ows_Amount_x0020__x0028_LC_x0029_"] != null)
{
    str.AppendLine("<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF';align='right';> " + item["ows_Amount_x0020__x0028_LC_x0029_"].ToString() + "</td>");
}
```

Comment: What is with the weird naming? If its for Unicode, U+0020 is the ASCII space, which you could use just CamelCasing for.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I think SharePoint generated those column names, not the user

Comment: Well, his knowledge of HTML is lacking.

Comment: @ColeJohnson got the name from XML from the SharePoint Site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a standard number format string in the `ToString()` method of `Decimal` (or `Double`, or whatever the actual datatype is of your item):

```
Convert.ToDecimal(item["ows_Amount_x0020__x0028_LC_x0029_"]).ToString("N0");
```

The `"N0"` here means "Number" at `0` decimal places. If you don't want commas added, use `"F0"` instead.

Number format reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Convert.ToDecimal(item["ows_Amount_x0020__x0028_LC_x0029_"]).ToString("N1") //1 decimal place
```

OR

```
Convert.ToDecimal(item["ows_Amount_x0020__x0028_LC_x0029_"]).ToString("N0") //No decimal
```

OR

```
String.Format("{0:N1}", item["ows_Amount_x0020__x0028_LC_x0029_"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on the type of: item["ows_Amount_x0020__x0028_LC_x0029_"]

Assuming it is always an amount that happens to be a string such as: 56.78

Then you can use:

```
if (item["ows_Amount_x0020__x0028_LC_x0029_"] != null)
{
  decimal temp = 0;
  if (decimal.TryParse(item["ows_Amount_x0020__x0028_LC_x0029_"], out temp))
      str.AppendLine(" " + (long) temp + "");
  else
      str.AppendLine(" " + item["ows_Amount_x0020__x0028_LC_x0029_"].ToString() + "");
}
```